# Achieving S3 and Mongo file upload in Next.js 14 application

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, mongoose-schema

I am using Aws-S3 for one of my project file storages. The below code uploading files in a form but The challenges I am fetching to retrieve the object URL and push the s3 uploaded object URL to the Mongoose data model as string when call the POST method.

This is my code for Next.js 14

NB: If I have to try multer-s3 to get the locations as like Node.js then please share a code example.

/app/api/s3/route.js

```
export async function POST(request) {

try {

const formData = await request.formData();

const file = formData.get("file");



if (!file) {

return NextResponse.json({ error: "No file found" }, { status: 400 });

}



const buffer = Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer());

const fileName = file.name;

const contentType = file.type;

let folderName = "";



// Determine folderName based on file type

if (contentType.includes("image")) {

folderName = "image";

} else if (contentType === "application/pdf") {

folderName = "pdf";

} else {

return NextResponse.json(

{ error: "Unsupported file type" },

{ status: 400 }

);

}



await uploadFileToS3(buffer, fileName, contentType, folderName);



return NextResponse.json({ success: true, fileName });

} catch (error) {

console.error(error);

return NextResponse.json(

{ error: "Error uploading file" },

{ status: 500 }

);

}

}
```

This is my demo data model (just for understanding purpose):

```
{

Photo: {

type: String,

},

export const Team = mongoose.models.Team || mongoose.model("Team", teamSchema);
```

I want to store the uploaded file url store to the Mongoose model when submitting the form.

Comment: When you run this code, what are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: @Quassnoi The code uploading files perfectly but how do add the uploaded object url to the mongoose model?

Answer (score 0):

Import GetObjectCommand from the @aws-sdk/client-s3 library.
Import getSignedUrl from the @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner library.

Use the getSignedUrl function to get a signed URL of the image you recently uploaded. This URL give access to the image in your S3 bucket.
Save the URL to MongoDB.

Then use MongoDB function to store the obtained signed URL in your MongoDB database.

By the way this is how i did in express JS but the procedure will be same if you are calling MongoDB functions from NextJS.

```
import {
  S3Client,
  GetObjectCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";

const s3client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESSKEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESSKEY,
  },
});
```

i have made a helper function here which receive parameters here

```
export const getUrlOfImageFromS3 = async (key) => {
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "your bucket name",
    Key: key,
  });

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
  return url;
};
```

const url = await getUrlOfImageFromS3(fileKey);
Then i am saving this url to MONGODB with specific data.

let me know if you need any further help.